# Possible to disable smart card PIN change in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, group-policy, smartcard

I'm looking for a way to disable the smart card PIN change ability provided with Windows 7's native minidriver. It doesn't allow us to enforce any PIN complexity requirements such that users could change their PIN to 000000 or blank without any issues so we'd like to disable that ability.

I've been googling around and haven't found any way to do this, but perhaps someone has encountered a similar issue and found a resolution? A third party minidriver is the next step, but if we could do it without additional tools I'm all for it.

Comment: I tried looking this up today, alas no documentation exists, as far as I can tell, regarding disabling the self-service PIN change function.  I haven't had a chance to check if local machine policies can disallow it's use though.  Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: @BrentPabst Thanks for looking, that's the same conclusion I came to unfortunately.

Answer (score -4):

Try following Steps :

- Goto Run
- Type "services.msc"
- Search for "Smart Card" and double click on it.
- If service Status is Started then Stop it & set Startup type to Disable.
- Click on Apply & OK.

Hope this help you..

Comment: So the solution to a problem is simply to disable `ALL` of the functionality. c'mon. -1

Comment: Yeah, that's a bad idea. I need to maintain smartcard functionality but disable PIN change.